# How to shift the character only a to z or z to a using php?

Tags: php

```
$string = "abcfght";
$shift = 3;
$shiftedString = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $ascii = ord($string[$i]);
    $shiftedChar = chr($ascii-$shift);

    $shiftedString .= $shiftedChar;
}

echo $shiftedString;
```

> In the above code b shifted -3 so output is display according to asci table, but my expectation is that output "z"

Answer (score 0):

try this, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/794796)

```
$string = "abcfght";
$shift = 3;
$chars = str_split($string);
$arr = array_map(function($v){
  $shift = ord($v) -3;
  echo $shift."\n";
  return $shift < 97 ? chr($shift + 26) : chr($shift);
}, $chars);
echo implode('', $arr);
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. I edited it.